# Can't download file on put_file in PyWebIO

Tags: python, flask

I'm having a problem running the PyWebIO program in combination with flask
when I try to use put_file or download session from PyWebIO it produces an error like this and the file cannot be downloaded

[error status]

[image: 1]

and here's an example of the code I'm using

```
put_buttons(['Click to download'],[lambda: download('hello-world.txt', b'hello-world')])
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to upgrade your PyWebIO to lasest version via `pip install -U pywebio`. Or you can add `pywebio.session.hold()` in the end of your app function.

See also: https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/session.html#pywebio.session.hold